# How to clone a SD card from HP network attached photosmart printer using Linux?

Tags: linux, sd-card, disk-image, cloning

How to make a low level (file system unaware) cloning of a SD card inserted in an HP Photosmart printer, which is accessible via a local network ?

```
smb://192.168.1.58
```

(192.168.1.58 is my printer IP)
In Firefox or Ubuntu's Nautilus file explorer, above adress lists a "MEMORY_CARD" storage.
However, I cannot access it (probably because the card is corrupted).

Trying to mount it:

```
mount -t cifs //192.168.1.58/MEMORY_CARD /mnt/photosmart/ -o username=guest,password=hp
```

returns:
   mount: Not a directory

I checked that both locations exists, i.e. "MEMORY_CARD" as well as "/mnt/photosmart/".

Instead of mounting the storage, I want to image it with dd, ddrescue or equivalent, in order to perform data recovery afterwards.

But how to pass the network attached storage as parameter to the "dd" command ?

I heard about netcat and ssh but could not figure out how to use them in such case.
Thanks.

Comment: Maybe (not tested) `ssh guest@192.168.1.58 'dd if=/MEMORY_CARD' | dd of=/mnt/photosmart/imagedSDcard.img`

Comment: I tried above, but it does not work as it would require an SSH server to be present on the printer, and it doesn't seem being the case for the one that I'm using (HP Photosmart C309a). So, any alternative?